# Check for warnings of deprecation and new methods

Tags: ios, deprecated, uitabbaritem

Recently I submitted my app on AppStore with a method setting badgecolor of tabbaritem.

```
    [[[AppDelegate globalDelegate].tabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:1].tabBarItem.badgeColor = kTabBarBadgeColor;
```

This badgeColor came in iOS 10 only and my app supported iOS 8 and above. I had no idea about it and the app got approved. Now, I have to resubmit my app with fixing this issue.

I want to know if there is a way to find out such cases where methods get deprecated or are visible in specific OS versions only.

Comment: In this case you need to change the target of your xcode project  to iOS 8 and then build and run the project xcode will gives the error and warnings.

Comment: thanks @AshishKakkad

Comment: thanks @AshishKakkad but it is very difficult to check each and every code line before writing.

Answer (score 0):

By changing target of Xcode project you can see errors & warnings while building.

If you need more info,
You can visible all API changes like `Added,Modified & Deprecated` variants in [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation)

it will give you searching options for both Swift & Objective C

[image]

Searching UITabBarItem Instance Property `badgeColor`. it gives API changes are none.Supporting SDK's version

```
SDKs
iOS 10.0+
tvOS 10.0+
```

Searching `finishedSelectedImage` instance method of UITabBarItem.

```
SDK
iOS 5.0–7.0 Deprecated
```

> Deprecated Use selectedImage with UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal
>   instead.

Comment: thanks. can you share a link to this. How do I change the target for my target, I have deployment target set to iOS 8.